# Free group action on a measure space

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, ergodic-theory

I'm working through the book "Ergodic Theory, Independence and Dichotomies by David Kerr and Hanfeng Li." They define a group action on a probability space to be free if there is a G-invariant set $X_0\subseteq X$ with $\mu(X_0)=1$ such that if $sx=x$ for some $x\in X_0$ and $s\in G$ then $s=e$ the identity. It is also claimed that if the action is free then $sA\cap A=\emptyset$ for some measurable nonnull subset $A$.

However this does not seem intuitive to me. Suppose you had a $s\in G$, $s\neq e$, and $q\in sA\cap A$, so $q\in A$ and there is an $a\in A$, $q\neq a$ such that $sa=q$. Then the intersection $sA\cap A$ would contain $q$, yet no point needs to be stabilized by the action.

Comment: The statement being claimed is unclear. How is $A$ quantified? Is it "for all $A$ this property is satisfied"? Or "there exists $A$ such that this property is satisfied"? Or are their hidden constraints on $A$ (for example $A \subset X_0$)?

Comment: My bad, $A$ is not just measurable but nonnull. Fixed it.

Comment: You still miss a quantifier for $s$. Do you mean: For each $s\in G-\{e\}$ there is a measurable non-null subset $A\subset X$ with $sA\cap A=\emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, $s\in G-\{e\}$

Comment: There is no need to close this. It is well-considered and the OP is clearly responsive.

Comment: @BrendanMallery dude, you need to make quantifiers clear, especially after people ask. you still haven't said what the quantifier on $s$ is, and I guessed what the quantifier on $A$ was and added it to the question.